# Apache 2.4 mod_rewrite and Location ProxyPass

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

My config is looking like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/data/(images/.*) /data-server/$1 [PT]
<Location /data/>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/data/
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
<Location /data-server/>
    ProxyPass ajp://localhost:8009/data-server/
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
...
```

However, the `RewriteRule` with a passthrough flag [PT] is not working as intended - httpd ends up looking for the file in `htdocs` instead of using the `ProxyPass` directive.

Is there a way to do a *real* passthrough during a rewrite, to force httpd to follow all of the logic, including Location sections?

Or do `mod_rewrite` and `mod_proxy` never work together?

Comment: Yes mod_proxy works with mod_rewrite. If you use the [P flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html) it will proxy to the location specified directly.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug in 2.4.  I had a similar issue when migrating from 2.2 to 2.4.  I had to pull the ProxyPass directives out of the Location section like so:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/data/(images/.*) /data-server/$1 [PT]
<Location /data/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Location>
ProxyPass /data/ ajp://localhost:8009/data/
<Location /data-server/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Allow from all
</Location> 
ProxyPass /data-server/ ajp://localhost:8009/data-server/
```